# running matplotlib in jupyter notebook but getting error as <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

Tags: matplotlib, size

I'm running code  in jupyter notebook but not getting graph instead a msg saying <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

```
import random
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')


x_vals=[]
y_vals=[]
index=count()

def animate(i):
    x_vals(next(index))
    y_vals(random.randint(0,5))
    
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)

ani=FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've used this  '%matplotlib notebook' but after running code, I'm only getting the upper left side of graph is visible and I'm using offline jupyter notebook

Comment: There was a bug that should be fixed n 3.3.1 where chrome browser and matplotlib did not play well together.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem of web browser.
I was test that in explore. Same result

Who is know this